# Goodness of Fit Using $CDF$

Tags: goodness-of-fit, cumulative-distribution-function

I don't have a tremendous amount of experience with testing goodness of fit, and I've just begun studying it rigorously.  A though occurred to me, and since it occurred to me, I'm sure it exists, and is probably called "naive (something)."

If I have a continuous distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ with $CDF$, $g$, and a set of values $X = \{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ drawn $i.i.d$ from this distribution, isn't the set $Y = \{g(x_1), \dots, g(x_n)\}$ of interest?  Aren't these $i.i.d$ draws from the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$?  Doesn't this reduce the problem of goodness of fit in this case, to understanding goodness of fit of the uniform distribution?

I know not all distributions on $\mathbb{R}$ have closed form $CDF$s, and in order to extend this to discrete distributions one would have to add sampling from the mass associated with $x_i$ in each case, but this still seems pretty reasonable to me.

My questions are: does a theory along these lines exists (if so, what's it called?)?  What are the limitations of this idea?  Any references, or packages?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goodness of fit is of concern when $g$ is *estimated* from the data, and herein lies the rub: in the formula for $Y$, you have to understand that "$g$" itself is random (and conditional on all the $x_i$).

You will have used some kind of procedure (which for simplicity let's assume is non-randomized)

$$t_n:\mathbb{R}^n\to \Omega$$

(where $\Omega$ is some prespecified set of possible distributions on $\mathbb{R}$) to create the estimate

$$\hat G = t_n(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n).$$

When $\hat G$ is continuous let its density be $\hat g$, with $\hat g(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\hat G(x)$, allowing us to write

$$Y = (\ldots, \frac{d}{dx} t_n(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)(x) |_{x=X_i},\ldots)$$

for iid random variables $X_i$.  **$Y_i$ will almost never have a uniform distribution.**  (See below for an example.)

**The idea is a good one, though.**  The right way to capitalize on it is via the likelihood, which also is a function of the $\hat g(x_i)$.  You compare the fit to one obtained with a model that could capture lack of fit and use a [deviance statistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_%28statistics%29).  The art lies in identifying the likely forms in which reality could differ from the original model and including them in a superset of distributions $\Omega^\prime \supset \Omega$.

---

I have not offered a mathematical proof of the key assertion that the components of $Y$ are rarely uniform, for two reasons.  First, the detailed notation should at least suggest the situation is more complicated than indicated by the original notation (in the question) that assumes $g$ is known.  Second, it suffices only to provide a counterexample.  One that nobody could impugn as "pathological" is the standard estimator of a Normal distribution,

$$(\hat \mu, \hat \sigma^2) = \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i, \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \hat\mu)^2\right).$$

The results of a quick, easy simulation (in `R`) are decidedly non-uniform in the tails.

[image: Figure: histogram and qq plot of the simulation]

The left hand side is a histogram of all $3\times 1000$ values of $g(x_i)$ for $1000$ independent simulations of size $n=3$.  The right hand side is its uniform Q-Q plot.  A uniform histogram would have bars of approximately equal height.  A uniform Q-Q plot would lie extremely close to a diagonal line.  The visually evident deviations in these plots reveal the non-uniformity.

```r
set.seed(17)                        # Allows these results to be reproduced exactly
n <- 3                              # Sample size
n.sim <- 1e3                        # Number of simulation trials
x <- matrix(rnorm(n*n.sim), nrow=n) # Data are in columns
m <- colMeans(x)
s <- apply(x, 2, sd)
y <- mapply(pnorm, x, m, s)         # Columns are the g(x_i)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(y)
plot(sort(y), type="l", main="Uniform QQ Plot of y")
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a whole collection of such tests, collectively called ECDF-tests* - intended for fully specified distributions, that have this property.

*(short for 'empirical CDF', since they compare the sample cdf to the fully specified one in some way)

The property you mention makes those tests distribution-free -- the distribution of the test statistic will be the same no matter the form of the original fully specified cdf.

These tests include the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, the Cramér-von Mises and the Anderson-Darling test (among others).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93von_Mises_criterion#Cram.C3.A9r.E2.80.93von_Mises_test_.28one_sample.29

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test

A good starting place might be D'Agostino, R.B. & Stephens, M.A. *Goodness of fit techniques*

Comment: I believe these tests don't really work as described in the question.  They use different test statistics, do not directly examine the uniformity of the $g(x_i)$, and are not equivalent to testing their uniformity.

Comment: @whuber, the entirety of Chapter 8 of D'Agostino and Stephens is about tests for the uniform distribution, and they preface the chapter by saying these tests arise naturally from transforming X values to U values. They specifically mention the probability integral transform in section 8.3. They discuss using the KS, AD, and CvM tests on the transformed uniform observations as well in sections 8.6. So I this Glen is not incorrect; at most incomplete.

Comment: @Avraham I don't have immediate access to that text, but I would bet that the probability transform in question is based on a *prespecified* distribution rather than one fit from the data. That's certainly the case with the KS test.  These tests need modification (such as the Lilliefors variant of KS) when testing goodness of fit to an *estimated* distribution precisely because the distribution of the $\{\hat g(x_i)\}$ is *not* uniform.

Comment: @whuber my opening sentence explicitly says "fully specified distributions". As far as I understood the question that's what it was asking about. It's possible I missed something about the question, but my answer doesn't purport to apply where it doesn't, since it clearly says what it's talking about.

Comment: @Glen Could you then please clarify the parenthetical remark, "ECDF for empirical CDF"? This caused me to think that by "fully specified distribution" you meant any distribution as estimated from the data. Your subsequent remark about "distribution free" becomes rather puzzling if you intend to apply these tests to what now seems to be a zero-dimensional family of distributions!

Comment: @whuber Sorry to have confused you. I'll try to clarify with some edits. The ECDF comment was an afterthought - an attempt to clarify the abbreviation for anyone unfamiliar with the term ECDF